# simple line drawing/graphics on title page and page header

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, titles

I'm experienced with Latex but more or less plain Latex without much graphical content. Anyway, I'm trying to create a template for invoices and other official documents. Therefore I want a simple design that follows a corporate identity.

**Question:** But I have no idea how to add those blue lines both to the title page and to the default page style (odd and even). I had a look at the TikZ package but I have no idea how to apply & place it on a page or inside a page header.

Any help is appreciated.

This would be a design of a title page including the company details on the right and a logo on the upper right.

[image: title page]

This is a design of a default even/odd page having a header including the blue line and the document title.

[image: default page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct the frame with `tikzpicture` using the options `remember picture,overlay`. In the picture you can refer to the corners of the page using `(current page.north west)` etc.

Then use the command `\AddEverypageHook` provided by the package `everypage` to add the frame to, well, every page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\myframe
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[rounded corners=20pt,blue]
      ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-1in)$)
      rectangle
      ($(current page.south east) + (-1in,1in)$);
    \draw[red,thick]
      ($(current page.north west) + (1in+\oddsidemargin,-(1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep)$)
      -- +(\textwidth,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\AddEverypageHook{\myframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\Blindtext
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks. So you would do a similar frame for the title page and add that one only once without using the AddEverypageHook?

Comment: @Matthias Yes, add `\myframe` to `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}`, or before the final `\clearpage` of the title page. I understood your question as asking how to add the frame everywhere.

Comment: Question was towards title page and default pages :) but your solution is great. Thanks

Comment: @Matthias Probably a different understanding of what *"default page style (odd and even)"* means. Great, if your problem is solved ...

Comment: one more question: do you know how to refer to the text-left-start. I mean how to make the line start where the text starts? You using the page.north etc but without the boundaries.

Comment: @Matthias I've added a red line on top of the text area. You have to calculate the position by adding the various widths and heights and seps that make up the page layout. See e.g. [Wikibooks LaTeX/Page Layout](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout).

Comment: Nice, thank you. I was trying the same but missed some of the widths/heights. I'm trying to add the text above the line. Tried it with Fanchdr but didn't succeed. Gonna try your version with text instead of the red line.